# Android: Difference between WebView and default Browser (core, js engine, HTML5, URI schemes support etc.)

Tags: android, api, browser

could I know whats the difference from the tech point of view between these two? Is there something that default browser can handle and WebView cannot by default? 
Thank you

Mosh